# Does dissolving an ester shift the chemical equilibrium?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Esters are fairly insoluble in water , however one of the products of an esterification reaction is water , hence by washing the ester as a method of purification you are adding more water and increasing the concentration of water , would this not cause an equilibrium shift and hence result in a lower concentration of the ester ?

Comment: It would, if not for the fact that the reaction is pretty slow.